# Should I regenerate cookies CookieStore using apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to login to external web site, and use HttpClient in combination with CookieStore. As a guide I used http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomContext.java and http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html

Here is my code:

```
    RequestConfig globalConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.BEST_MATCH).build();
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    context.setCookieStore(cookieStore);

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(globalConfig)
            .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
            .build();

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlAddress);

    httpGet.addHeader("Accept", "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*");
    httpGet.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.7,ru;q=0.3");
    httpGet.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
    httpGet.addHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate");
    //httpGet.addHeader("Host", host); // should I copy host here?
    httpGet.addHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

    CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

    List<Cookie> cookies1 = context.getCookieStore().getCookies();

    try {
        System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine());
        HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
        // do something useful with the response body
        streamToFile(entity1.getContent(), "./login_result_1.html");

        // and ensure it is fully consumed
        EntityUtils.consume(entity1);
    } finally {
        response1.close();
    }
```

That works fine.

When I do further request to the site, should I do any special code to pass cookies obtained in the request above?

**Should I regenerate cookies or that will be done by Apache?**

I was not able to find clear answer. Also my further request is not handled by web site properly and it doesn't allow me to login.

```
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlAddress);
    httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*");
    httpPost.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.7,ru;q=0.3");
    httpPost.addHeader("Referer", "http://virtonomica.ru/");
    httpPost.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
    httpPost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate");

    httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpPost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    //httpPost.addHeader("Host", "virtonomica.ru");
    //httpPost.addHeader("Content-Length", "51");//LENGTH
    httpPost.addHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    httpPost.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps)); // nvps is List<NameValuePair> which contains POST data

    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Please advise.

Comment: Are you using the same `cookieStore` reference?

Comment: The code above is written in a single function (prototype) so yes, cookiesStore is the same. In fact, I use the same instance of httpClient so I assume cookiesStore is also reused.